# Microsoft CognitiveServices Speech class SpeechRecognizer, cannot gather a resulting text

Tags: c#, async-await, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I cannot get the the text from the wav file using SpeechRecognizer class.

When I debug  the code under I see that when I delay  I get  text but it eventually crashes.

Is the code incorrect?

What am I  missing inorder to wait on all the results and collect them in totalText which is a field variable.

```
using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(wavFile))
{
    using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(configuration, audioInput))
    {
        recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                totalText += e.Result.Text;

            }
            else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
            }
        };

        recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");

            if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
            }

            stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
        };

        recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n    Session started event.");
        };

        recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
            stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
        };

        recognizer.SpeechEndDetected += (s, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SpeechEndDetected: Did you update the subscription info?");
            SaveFile(totalText);
            stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
        };

        // Starts continuous recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
        await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Waits for completion.
        // Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.
        Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });

        // Stops recognition.
        await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (totalText != string.Empty)
        {
            SaveFile(totalText);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this result in the end.

```
The program '[9312] testhost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to the above code was done synchronously instead of async thus causing erratic behaviour.